# Highlight differences between two ranges

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to compare and find differences between to ranges of data as per below:

[image: My Example]

My Question is if I can do it without using VBA, using Conditional formatting instead.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: you want to calculate the difference? or you want to highlight those that have difference?

Comment: Hi Rosetta, the ones that have a difference: 44, -43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will give you the answer for one side, hope you'll figure out the other side. :)

> 1. create a new formatting rule for selected cells.

Here is the formula `=ABS(VLOOKUP($F5,$B:$C,2,0)) <> ABS($G5)`

[image]

> 2. apply the formatting rule to the selected cells.

[image]

For the other side, create a new formatting rule, using the same formula - just adjust the formula to mirror the lookup, and apply the rule to the correct cells. Have fun!

Comment: **Many Thanks** @Rosetta You have save my day.Will be possible to highlight if the supplier exist in one range but not in the other???

Comment: You're welcome. Yes can... create a new formatting rule using this formula `=ISERROR(VLOOKUP($F5,$B:$C,2,0))`. And similarly create a new rule for the other side with the adjusted formula.